# Reading bytes over TCP and encoding to ISO-8859-9 in Go

Tags: go, unicode

I am new to Golang. I am developing a service which reads bytes from remote address over TCP. The problem is that I can not change encoding of bytes I read. I want to convert the bytes I read to ISO-8859-9 string. Here is part of reading code.

```
 conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", constant.ConnectHost+":"+constant.ConnectPort)
 checkError(err)
 defer conn.Close()

 reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
 textproc := textproto.NewReader(reader)

 bytes, err := textproc.R.ReadBytes(constant.EndTextDelimiter)
 checkError(err)
 msg := string(bytes[:])
```

Code works fine. But the encoding is different than I want. It is a problem for receiving service. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding, https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap#ISO8859_9

Comment: @Peter I used "bytes, err = charmap.ISO8859_9.NewEncoder().Bytes(bytes)" but it returns "rune not supported by encoding" error. I searched for hours, still same.

Comment: Your text includes runes that have no equivalent in ISO-8859-9, i.e. you're trying to do something that's technically impossible. It's not for us to decide how to deal with that. The encoding package has things like [ReplaceUnsupported](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding#ReplaceUnsupported) and [HTMLEscapeUnsupported](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding#HTMLEscapeUnsupported) but their use is "strongly discouraged".

Comment: @TugrulBayrak Perhaps what's needed is to `decode` the ISO8859_9 bytes into UTF-8 https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding#Decoder

Comment: @Peter yes you are right. I was trying to encode Turkish letters to Turkish letters again. That's the problem. That's why it wasn't allow me to encode. Because encoding function wants an utf8 format. Thanks for help!

Comment: @karmakaze after you said, first I decode the incoming ISO8859_9 bytes to UTF-8, Then I did my process, at the end I encode this UTF-8 to ISO8859_9. Finally it works! Thanks for help. I will edit question.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. Please roll back your recent edit and post the solution as an answer instead. You are allowed and even encouraged to mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @tripleee I changed it. Also I will accept my answer tomorrow. Thanks for your advice, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

charmap.ISO8859_9.NewEncoder().Bytes() function wants UTF-8 format to encode. I was getting error when I try to encode my bytes. Because my incoming bytes are in 8859-9 format and I was trying to convert them directly. First I decode the bytes to UTF-8 format. I did my process, at the end I encoded this UTF-8 bytes to ISO8859-9 unicode using encoder. Here is the new code.

```
//main package
bytes, err := textproc.R.ReadBytes(constant.EndTextDelimiter)
checkError(err)
msg := encoder.DecodeISO8859_9ToUTF8(bytes)
//..........
// Process that string, create struct Then convert struct to json bytes
// Then encode that bytes
json := encoder.EncodeUTF8ToISO8859_9(bytes)

//encoder package
package encoder
import "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"

func DecodeISO8859_9ToUTF8(bytes []byte) string {
    encoded, _ := charmap.ISO8859_9.NewDecoder().Bytes(bytes)
    return string(encoded[:])
}

func EncodeUTF8ToISO8859_9(bytes []byte) string {
    encoded, _ := charmap.ISO8859_9.NewEncoder().Bytes(bytes)
    return string(encoded[:])
}
```