# Golang decode string with literal \xnn

Tags: go

How can I convert the string `Joe Doe\xE2\x80\x99s iPhone` to `Joe Doe’s iPhone`

The string source is `regexp` processing the output of `iwlist wlan0 scan`

Under the hood it is:

```
const text  = "Joe Doe\\xE2\\x80\\x99s iPhone"
```

Thought of refeed it as literal or use packages like `strconv` but none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strconv.Unquote` can parse it with surrounding quotes.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    const text = "Joe Doe\\xE2\\x80\\x99s iPhone"

    s, _ := strconv.Unquote(`"` + text + `"`)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

```
Joe Doe’s iPhone
```

https://go.dev/play/p/wYBcfesjLI_J

Comment: Nice idea! the source is an iPhone wifi hotspot broadcast as seen by the output of `iwlist wlan0 scan`

Comment: `strconv.Unquote` threw me off at first (giving `invalid syntax` as its error) because I had forgotten the surrounding quotes. Nevermind the URL encoding roundtrip. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace just this substring "\xE2\x80\x99", strings.Replace function may solve your problem.

```
result := strings.Replace(text, "\xE2\x80\x99", "'", -1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but its reasonable to expect other variations as well

Comment: Then your problem is about encoding and decoding.  That's why you can not get correct character. If you encode your string to correct format, you will solve it. check my other question here, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173628/reading-bytes-over-tcp-and-encoding-to-iso-8859-9-in-go/59190743#59190743  and charmap package : https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap